# How to resolve Internal Server Error - PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I've checked over, and over, and over again. I'm new to using prepared statements so unless I'm doing something wrong.

This worked before I added all the fields. It worked when it was just username and password. - I check all my names for my textboxes, they all match up. My database column names also match up perfectly to the code.

Can someone please help me? I'm on my witts end with this prepared statements crap and I'm ready to jump ship.

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'lib/password.php';
require 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['register'])){

$username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
$pass = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;
$email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;
$firstname = !empty($_POST['firstname']) ? trim($_POST['firstname']) : null;
$lastname = !empty($_POST['lastname']) ? trim($_POST['lastname']) : null;
$profileurl = !empty($_POST['profileurl']) ? trim($_POST['profileurl']) : null;
$steam64id = !empty($_POST['steam64id']) ? trim($_POST['steam64id']) : null;
$steamurl = !empty($_POST['steamurl']) ? trim($_POST['steamurl']) : null;


$sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM users WHERE username = :username";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row['num'] > 0){
    alert("Username already exists!");
    die();
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(email) AS num FROM users WHERE email = :email";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);

$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row['num'] > 0){
    alert("Email already exists!");
    die();
}

$passwordHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password, truckermpurl, steam64id, steamurl, username) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :truckermpurl, :steam64id, steamurl, username)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindValue(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);
$stmt->bindValue(':truckermpurl', $profileurl);
$stmt->bindValue(':steam64id', $steam64id);
$stmt->bindValue(':steamurl', $steamurl);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);


$result = $stmt->execute();

if($result){
    //What you do here is up to you!
    alert("Thanks for registering.");
    exit();
}

}

?>
```

Comment: try error reporting in php

Comment: What's wrong exactly? any errors?

Comment: You've got a whole bunch of "stuff" there... Have you just tried doing a cut down example using only a single sql statement to see if that works?

Comment: I got this: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /home/picmoun2/public_html/picmount.ca/testpanel/register.php:88 Stack trace: #0 /home/picmoun2/public_html/picmount.ca/testpanel/register.php(88): PDOStatement->bindValue(':truckersmpurl', 'dfsdf') #1 {main} thrown in /home/picmoun2/public_html/picmount.ca/testpanel/register.php on line 88

Comment: Yet it is defined $truckersmpurl = !empty($_POST['profileurl']) ? trim($_POST['profileurl']) : null;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 3):

You are expecting parameter

```
$stmt->bindValue(':steamurl', $steamurl);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
```

But, you have declared in your prepared statement SQL

```
... , steamurl, username)"
```

which should be

```
... , :steamurl, :username)"
```

Comment: Yes. That was one of the immediate problems that would of caused it, I fixed that but it turned out there was still a variable giving me trouble so I fixed it by using my solution below!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by changing the database column name and variable name. Weird. Maybe it was just something I was overlooking. That being said, it seems the alert()'s were also causing me troubles so I used

```
$_SESSION['errormessage']
header('location: error.php')
```

where error.php will echo my session error message. works perfectly now! Maybe this could help someone else.